# Windows: How to show environment when using pipenv?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, pipenv

Windows 10

My current powershell base environment

```
PS C:\Users\micah\Dev\try-zappa> pip freeze
certifi==2018.11.29
pipenv==2018.11.26
virtualenv==16.4.0
virtualenv-clone==0.5.1
```

When I run `pipenv shell`, it takes me to my new environment.

```
PS C:\Users\micah\Dev\try-zappa> pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\micah\Dev\try-zappa> pip freeze
argcomplete==1.9.3
awacs==0.8.2
awscli==1.16.106
boto3==1.9.96
botocore==1.12.96
certifi==2018.11.29
cfn-flip==1.1.0.post1
```

However, just by looking at the command line I see `PS C:\Users\micah\Dev\try-zappa>` and not something descriptive that shows me that my environment is active like when you use pip and activate an environment. (e.g. `(try-zappa) PS C:\Users\micah\Dev\try-zappa>`

Does anyone know how to turn this on? I'd hate to think I was in one environment, but to actually be in another.

Comment: Please consider marking an answer as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I could not confirm my hypothesis right now but:

- `pipenv` itself does not change the command prompt in one's shell
- one needs to activate a plugin for one's shell (powershell in your case) to change prompt on activating-deactivating virtualenv.

I suppose that you need [virtualenvwrapper-powershell](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper-powershell/2.7.1)

Comment: There is also [PS Gallery - PSVirtualEnv](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSVirtualEnv)